# TypeError: callback.apply is not a function after allowDiskUse

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection having 1Million documents... I have passed the option for `allowDiskUse` and now it is throwing error

`TypeError: callback.apply is not a function`

I have searched for this but could get the solution... Please help

```
const pictures = await Picture.aggregate([
      { $sort: { createdAt: -1 }},
      { $group: {
        _id: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$createdAt" } },
        pictures: {
          $push: {
            _id: '$_id',
            image: '$image',
            time: { $dateToString: { format: "%H:%M:%S", date: "$createdAt" } }
          }
        }
      }},
      { $limit: 50 },
      { $project: {
        _id: false,
        createdAt: '$_id',
        pictures: '$pictures'
      }}
    ], { allowDiskUse: true })
```

Mongodb version - 3.6

Mongoose version - 5.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because this is "mongoose". There is no "options" block on the `aggregate()` method [in the Mongoose API](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/model.js#L3003). That's the source link and then [the documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_aggregate). Note the returned [`<Aggregate>`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Aggregate) type.

That chains to [`allowDiskUse(true)`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-allowDiskUse) as demonstrated in the documentation:

```
await Model.aggregate(..).allowDiskUse(true).exec()
```

You should really never need to use the option in most aggregations. Getting a warning message is usually an indicator that you are actually missing an index, or indeed any sane attempt to [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) and filter down results.