# Mongodb: allowDiskUse: true is not working in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongo query which have multiple lookup but it returns me a error

**Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in**

I already add allow disk size true in my aggregation query

`await Service.aggregate(pipeline)
      .allowDiskUse(true)
      .exec();`

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using, and what sort of an aggregate operation are you performing? I don't think `allowDiskUse` works with all of them.

Comment: Are you connecting to a MongoDB deployment that you have installed, or a cloud service? If you are using a cloud service (particularly a free tier) the `allowDiskUse` option may not be supported.

Comment: @Caffeinated.tech version 5.2.7, 

`services.aggregate([ { '$addFields': { name_lc: { '$toLower': '$name.value_en' } } }, { '$match': { isDeleted: false } }, { '$lookup': { from: 'servicecategories', localField: 'serviceCategory', foreignField: '_id', as: 'category' } }, { '$sort': { name_lc: 1 } }, { '$skip': 0 }, { '$limit': 10 }, { '$project': { 'category.defaultQuantities': 0 } } ], { allowDiskUse: true })`

Comment: @Stennie i am using mongo atlas paid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: callback.apply is not a function after allowDiskUse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50756344/typeerror-callback-apply-is-not-a-function-after-allowdiskuse)

Comment: Is your paid Atlas cluster shared tier (M2 or M5)? The `allowDiskUse` option currently requires a dedicated cluster (M10+) - see [Operational Limitations](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/free-shared-limitations/#operational-limitations).

Answer (score 6):

Is your paid Atlas cluster shared tier (M2 or M5)? The `allowDiskUse` option currently requires a dedicated cluster (M10+) - see [Operation Limitation](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/free-shared-limitations#operational-limitations). NB. this is from @stennie

Comment: Thanks, you saved a lot of my time. I was concerned that my syntax was wrong but in the end, I found out that my company had downgraded to an M5 (General) shared cluster for cost-cutting, which is why my allowDiskUse option was not working.